# MySQL subquery with multiple return values in WHERE clause returns empty set

Tags: mysql

When using a subquery in a WHERE conditional the query returns empty set:

If I do: (1)

```
USE general_db;
SELECT * FROM general_db.master WHERE alert IN ('M1_001','G1_011');
+------+-------------+
| mkey | alert       |
+------+-------------+
|   17 | G1_011      |
|   19 | M1_001      |
+------+--------+----+
```

(1) works as expected.

Then I do: (2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME AS 'alert' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='maintenance_db';
+-------------+
| alert       |
+-------------+
| G1_011      |
| M1_001      |
+-------------+
```

(2) Works as expected.

But then if I use the second query (2) as a subquery of the first (1): (3)

```
SELECT * FROM general_db.master WHERE alert IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME AS 'alert' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='maintenance_db');

Empty set (0,00 sec)
```

(3) does not work as expected. I would think it should return the same results as in (1).

How can I do for the combination of both (3) to return the same results as in (1)? And why is this query (3) not working?

**More info:**

As you have may noticed, the table names in *maintenance_db*, may be contained in a column named *alert* in *master* table thats inside the *general_db*.

It is very strange. I am sure the subquery syntax is correct, this query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM general_db.master WHERE alert IN (SELECT alert FROM general_db.master WHERE alert IN ('G1_011','M1_001'));
```

So I think it may be something related to query (2).

This works:

```
USE maintenance_db;
select * from M1_001;
select * from G1_011;
```

So the names are correct I guess.

Thanks

Comment: Do you also `USE general_db;` in (3)?

Comment: @GSerg Yes. I do not change to other databases. At least not explicitly.

Comment: Instead of usign **master** could you please use **general_db.master** and try

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Just tried it out but there is no difference. I will edit the question to add this remark.

Comment: How can I be entirely sure the table names do not contain spaces or such ? Maybe they are not equal to 'M1_001' and may be 'M1_001  '.

Comment: `select 'it does not matter' from dual where 'abc' in ('abc ');` `select 'it does not matter' from dual where 'abc' = 'abc ';`

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353922/mysql-select-data-from-dynamic-table-names

Comment: This is already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353922/mysql-select-data-from-dynamic-table-names

Answer (score 1):

Why you are fetching table names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS instead of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES table!? There's no WHERE for filtering by column names in COLUMNS table!

What about:

```
SELECT * 
FROM general_db.master 
WHERE TRIM(alert) IN 
(
    SELECT UPPER(TABLE_NAME) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='maintenance_db'
)
```

Also instead of using inner query why not to use simple JOIN like

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM general_db.master m
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON (UPPER(t.table_name)=TRIM(m.alert) AND t.table_schema='maintenance_db')
```

Comment: The second query works!  But the first returns an empty set (the subqueries work by themself, but not when joined as one)

Comment: Depends how your MySQL server is set to manage table names: case sensitive or case insensitive. One can setup it inside MYSQL.INI file. Try with UPPPER-ing table names. By default MySQL stores table names in lower case while your entries are upper cased.

Comment: Tried: SELECT * FROM general_db.master WHERE alert IN (SELECT UPPER(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='maintenance_db'); but it returns empty set.

Comment: Maybe your data has trimming spaces. Try using TRIM() function.

Comment: Tried different combinations using: TRIM(UPPER(TABLE_NAME)), TRIM(TABLE_NAME), TRIM(alert) and TRIM(UPPER(alert)), still returns empty set